# Javascript set list item to variable list-style-type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fetching some data from data.txt and building a list with that using a script.
I want to set some variable value from data.txt to replace the bullet in an ordinary list-item, which I think is related to listStyleType.

The following almost works, but sets every bullet to the string `"abcd"`

```
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.style.listStyleType = '"abcd"';
```

so I expected to make this work for a variable by doing

```
//assume we loop over each line in data.txt
var values = line.split(';');
var id = values[0];
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.style.listStyleType = id;
```

however, that returns ordinary bullets again, instead of the `id` values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but a solution is to replace

```
listItem.style.listStyleType = id;
```

by

```
listItem.style.listStyleType = '"' + id + ' "';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).